# Can the Internet sharing on proxy network be tracked?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-sharing

In my office I have Mac Mini that is connected to an ethernet cable for internet. They don't allow us to use the office wifi on mobile etc.

So what I am going to do now, is create hotspot out of my Mac Mini machine for my Lumia-520 running at Windows 8.10 phone's use.

But I want to know if it can be tracked as the office Mac is already on a proxy network. Will the IT guys come to know about it?

And if yes.. if they can know what are the ways I can hide it using my Windows phone or MAC?

Comment: Whilst not at all specific to Windows Phone, sharing a connection is always detectable (even at the trivial sense with the proxy seeing "unusual" user agents)

Comment: All sorts of ways to detect and track that... different MAC addresses,  for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a tethering connection, no need to go through the proxy (you'll have to disable proxy, maybe by using a different browser for convenience) and they won't be able to see it.

They will eventually detect that you're using tethering, but they won't see what you're doing.

(Use at your own risks, but i think you already know that. I used to use my android phone to access unrestricted internet from office through an Ubuntu virtual machine)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the phone via the hotspot. So this is what happens when you do so.

Your Mac will create a hotspot and now will act like a router. So this means that all the data traffic will go through your Mac. So whatever device you connect to the Mac (which is the router now) will divert the traffic. It will act as a gateway. So that being the case, I think they will not be able to see your phone or its MAC since all they can see is the data traffic from your Mac mini.

The data from the site you query is sent back to your Mac and then your Mac in turn sends it to your phone. So this is the flow of data traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If the proxy is one configured by a router you will not be able to bypass it. If it's configured via WPAD you will be able to bypass it by visiting the Wi-Fi settings on your phone an choose to disable proxy.

You can setup a second proxy on your MAC and have your phone connect through it. You must also have the proxy change the HTTP User Agent (which will require you to install the proxys generated root certificate in order to change it for HTTPS traffic) to be sure that the phone isn't logged by the companys proxy.

Comment: @vaibhav, added how to hide your phone.